# How to aggregate data using apache beam api with multiple keys

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am new to google cloud data platform as well as to Apache beam api. I would like aggregate data based on multiple keys. In my requirement I will get a transaction feed having fields like customer id,customer name,transaction amount and transaction type. I would like to aggregate the data based on customer id & transaction type. Here is an example.

```
customer id,customer name,transction amount,transaction type
cust123,ravi,100,D
cust123,ravi,200,D
cust234,Srini,200,C
cust444,shaker,500,D
cust123,ravi,100,C
cust123,ravi,300,C

O/p should be

cust123,ravi,300,D
cust123,ravi,400,C
cust234,Srini,200,C
cust444,shaker,500,D
```

In google most of the examples are based on single key like group by single key. Can any please help me on how my PTransform look like in my requirement and how to produce aggregated data along with rest of the fields.

Regards,
Ravi.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way. I concatenated all the keys together to form a single key and then did the the sub and after than split the key to organize the output to a way you wanted. Please let me know if any question.

The code does not expect header in the CSV file. I just kept it short to show the main point you are asking.

```
import apache_beam as beam
import sys

class Split(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, element):
        """
        Splits each row on commas and returns a tuple representing the row to process
        """
        customer_id, customer_name, transction_amount, transaction_type = element.split(",")
        return [
            (customer_id +","+customer_name+","+transaction_type, float(transction_amount))
        ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
   p = beam.Pipeline(argv=sys.argv)
   input = 'aggregate.csv'
   output_prefix = 'C:\\pythonVirtual\\Mycodes\\output'

   (p
      | 'ReadFile' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input)
      | 'parse' >> beam.ParDo(Split())
      | 'sum' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum)
      | 'convertToString' >>beam.Map(lambda (combined_key, total_balance): '%s,%s,%s,%s' % (combined_key.split(",")[0], combined_key.split(",")[1],total_balance,combined_key.split(",")[2]))
      | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToText(output_prefix)
   )

   p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

it will produce output as below:

```
cust234,Srini,200.0,C
cust444,shaker,500.0,D
cust123,ravi,300.0,D
cust123,ravi,400.0,C
```

Comment: No worries mate. Did the suggestion work for you? Please accept the answer if it helped you.